# What is the best way to have two exclusive sets of filters above a data table?

Tags: tables, filter, data, toggle, tab

I have two sets of filters which work with the same data. There is a table of data below those two sets of filters.

But if one set of filters is applied, modified, i.e. worked with, I completely ignore the other set of filters while filtering the data. So, now my question is how could I put two sets of filters?

I was able to think about two options: using a switch button or adding tabs above the data table to switch between the filter sets.

Do you maybe have a better idea? And what would you recommend to happen when I switch from one filter set to another? Should there be default filters or should the filters be empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding tabs in the data table, you can add tabs inside the filter menu so that users can select which one to use without adding additional filters to the data table screen. This way, the user can select "filter" first, and then decide which one they want to use while being able to view the options instead of potentially clicking the first filter and then exiting out to view the options in the second filter.

If possible, I would have default options for switching back and forth between filters as well as saving their custom filter options once they select certain items.If a user changes filter 1 options and then switched to filter 2, the changes in filter 1 should be recalled when the user switches back to filter 1.

[image]